# Swift 5 - Set variable to plist value based on key

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Edit: Essentially, I cannot figure out how to return the Value in a plist based on the Key.

I am trying to create an app for myself in swift that, for now, has a singular focus - randomly selecting an image that I've put in the assets folder and showing that image. There will be a large number of these images, so manually typing the options won't work.

The steps I believe I need:

1. let variableA = "Item (arc4random_uniform(#))"
2. let variableB = [Value from plist that corresponds to Key from variableA]
3. Image(variableB)

Step 2 is the one that I cannot figure out.

I have a plist that's laid out like so:

[plist screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKsPP.png)

I know how to generate the random key with the below.

```
let variableA = "Item \(arc4random_uniform(#))"
// # is the number of images in the plist
```

I know how to generate the image of the asset just using the below.

```
var body: some View {
Image(variableB)
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()        
}
```

What I do not know and cannot figure out is how to make the app generate the random "Item #" from the first part, then select the corresponding name from the Value column of the plist using the "Item #" as the Key column, and then use that corresponding name Value to generate the image.

EDIT: I have updated the code and it is now the below. It is giving an error on the line with "do {" that states "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'".

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var variableB = ""
    var body: some View {
        let plist = "All Relics"
        do {
            let array = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([String].self, from: Data(plist.utf8))
            let imageName = array.randomElement()!
            print(imageName)
        } catch { print(error) }
        Image(variableB)
        .onAppear {
            if let array = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data),
                let imageName = array.randomElement() {
                    variableB = imageName
            }
         }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `arc4random_uniform` is outdated. Since Swift 4 there are native APIs

This is your plist containing 3 items

```
let plist = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>Some Name</string>
    <string>Some Other Name</string>
    <string>Something Different</string>
</array>
</plist>
"""
```

Simply decode the plist with `PropertyListDecoder` to `[String]` and get a `randomElement()`

```
do {
    let array = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([String].self, from: Data(plist.utf8))
    let imageName = array.randomElement()!
    print(imageName) 
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

In a SwiftUI enviroment create a `@State` variable

```
@State private var variableB = ""
```

and for example in `.onAppear` get the random string and assign it to `variableB` (`data` is the `Data` representation of the property list)

```
.onAppear {
     if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "All Relics", withExtension: "plist"),
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
        let array = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data),
        let imageName = array.randomElement() {
            variableB = imageName
    }
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate the information. I tried putting this all together, but I'm getting "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'" on the line with "do {" and "Expected 'else' after 'guard' condition" after the line with "let imageName = array.randomElement() {"

Comment: My bad, replace `guard` with `if`. The first snippet is just an example to be tested in a Playground.

Comment: Edit: I'm adding my updated code to the main post. When you say the "first snippet" is just an example, do you mean the plist or the "do {" part? The "do {" part is the only one returning that error "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'" on the same line. I tried googling that exact phrase, but it only brought up a single result and I'm not sure I understand what it's trying to tell me.

Comment: You cannot use the (entire) first snippet in a SwiftUi view body. It just shows the way how to decode the plist

Comment: Ah. So, then how would I get around that? The bits that I put together were from tutorials I was watching online and trying to piece together small bits here and there.

Comment: You need only the `onAppear` part. Delete the `do - catch` block. And you have to get the `Data` representing the plist. A literal string is not sufficient.

Comment: Apparently I can't chat yet, so I have to stick with commenting here. I apologize, I'm trying to understand. When you say "get the Data representing the plist", that's what I don't know how to do. When I tried googling, there's so many answers and none seem to work. When I delete the do - catch block, I still keep "let array =" and "let imageName =", correct?

Comment: No, delete everything from `let plist = .. ` to `...print(error) }`. The property list file must be somewhere, either on disk or online. You have to read the plist as `Data`.

Comment: Ah, okay. Understood. I have the plist loaded into the Swift project. It's listed below the Info.plist. When I remove everything from "let plist" to "print(error) }", the line under ".onAppear {" returns an error "Cannot find 'data' in scope". I believe "data" is from the plist, correct? That looks like something I'd need to set towards the top, but when I try some of the wording I've seen in google that includes ofType: "plist", for example, it just gives even more errors.

Comment: I added the code to read the data from the application bundle. The name of the file must be `All Relics.plist`. If the name does not match exactly or the file is not added to the target membership then nothing will happen.

Comment: You have just made my day more than I can express on here. I am using this with small images that I've taken on vacations to places I can unfortunately no longer get to. Thank you so very very much!